# Why is my stored procedure only working in SSMS , but not in the Reporting Services(SSRS)?

Tags: database, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'm working on putting many stored procedures into SSRS , and then you can view it on a website interface.. however, it's giving me issues.  Mainly, it only works when I run the `exec` manually but the "Report Manager" web-site comes up blank.

Could it have something to do with my having removed these lines(the direction I was given) , from the SPROC ? :

```
@DBStatus INT OUTPUT,
..and...
SELECT @DBStatus = @@ERROR
```

The reason I'm asking is because, when I run the SPROC manually , like so :

```
exec prc_Report_DataAnalysis 1, '20120818', '20120819', 16226
```

I just put "1" for the @DBStatus part.

Or does it have to do with `GRANT` commands?
My apologies for vagueness, i'm somewhat pokin in the dark..Any tips /pointers appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my coworker, I figured this out.  The problem was in my SSRS setup( within MS vis studio).  I didn't have the correct set-up in the "Report Data" left-hand pane..  So , I needed to :

Double-click the DataSets folder, then Rt. click 'DataSet1' and choose 'DataSet proerties' .. from tere I get [this box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cf5T.png):

[image]

Well .. before I had *not* selected 'Stored Procedure' , when I *should* have. The reason is because , I assumed that the wizard i used to get this up in the beginnin would suffice. But , in there I only entered a dummy SPROC to get it running.. which looks like so:

```
exec [dbo].[prc_RPT_Account_Summary]
@AccountID = 1,
@dtStart = '19001010',
@dtEnd = '19001010'
```

And so, I am starting to learn SSRS a littl.  thanks